# PostgreSQL lock row before delete?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I have a transaction in postgresql where I execute the following commands:

1. `SELECT "amount", "accountId" from "transactions" where "id" = "123"`
2. `DELETE from "transactions" where "id" = "123"`
3. `UPDATE "accounts" set "balance" = "balance" - amountFetchedInCommand1 where "id" = accountFetchedInCommand1`

Now I need to be sure that between command 1 and 2 the row fetched from `transactions` doesn't get modified (especially its `amount` and `accountId` fields).

Can I use a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement to lock the row fetched at command 1 even though I'm not going to update the row but only delete it?

Otherwise what's the best way to ensure this operation always run correctly?

(`transactions.accountId` is a foreign key linked to `account.id` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`)

Comment: Yes, you can use `select for update` but why do you need the `select` at all? Why not simply delete the row directly? Once it's deleted, no other transaction can modify it anyway. Btw: `"123"` is a column name not a number. You should use `where id = 123`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I need to fetch the "amount" value from it so I can update the balance in the linked "account" row

Comment: and postgresql doesn't return the deleted row

Comment: Postgres _does_ return the deleted row if you specify `returning`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're correct, I was using a library that doesn't support it and I thought it was a postgres behavior too.

Comment: You don't need the library to support that. You can do steps 2 and 3 in a single statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do step 2 and step 3 in a single statement:

```
with deleted as (
   DELETE from transactions 
   where id = 123
   return amount, "accountId"
)
UPDATE accounts 
   set balance = accounts.balance - d.amount 
from deleted d
where accounts.id = d."accountId";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Begin; //code Commit;

Or Start Transaction [parameters] //code Comit;

more documentation in: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-start-transaction.html

Comment: That wouldn't prevent the row from being modified between the `select` and the `delete` (unless `select for update` is used)